# Как записать List в файл?

Tags: c#, list, serialize

Есть информация, добавляется во время выполнения программы в лист, нужно записать этот лист в файл, и при каждом запуске программы, этот файл должен загружать эту информацию в лист, как это реализовать? (Или вместо файла в XML)

Comment: Что за лист? Какой тип?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если **список строк** то достаточно просто записывать так:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
...
lines.Add("line");

File.WriteAllLines(path);
```

Если же вы **не собираетесь работать** с файлом, а вам нужно просто дописывать значения (логирование, например), то лучше будет просто добавлять строки (чтобы не забарахлять память):

```
File.AppendAllLines(path, lines);
```

Если **список кастомного типа**, то проще будет серилизовать:

```
public List<MyClass> ReadAndDeserialize(string path)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        return (List<MyClass>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}

public void SerializeAndSave(string path, List<MyClass> data)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
    }
}
```

Документация:

- [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.WriteAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.AppendAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`XmlSerializer.Serialize()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdxxw552(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ваш метод `SerializeAndSave` по логике должен иметь тип возвращаемого значения `void`. Также я рекомендую подобные методы всегда делать generic'ами, возможно, с некоторыми ограничениями на T.

Comment: @Nikita согласен. Насчет дженериков - согласен, но это пример сугубо для текущего случая.